# Calculus/ zero or undefined ? with explanation

Tags: calculus

[image]

How can I know if the it suppose to be zero or undefined, because when I try to substitute in the original equation with 5/2 I will end up with a number and y. Same goes to (c) I will end up with x. So what shall I do?

It is more important to know the explanation rather than just the answer :) thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tangent that is horizontal line at a given point, (in the first case), has slope zero, and so $dy/dx = 0$ at $x = 5/2$.

In the latter case, you will have that $dy/dx$ is undefined. Just substitute $y = -13/2$ into the equation for $dy/dx$ to see that the denominator of $dy/dx$ is then equal to $0$ at that value, and so $dy/dx$ is undefined there, since we cannot have division by zero.

Comment: Yeah I know these two things and that is how I got my answers. finding the horizontal was to equal the nominator with 0 and to find the vertical is equal the denominator with 0 and solve.

Comment: But is that it? don't I need to substitute with answers that I got in the original equation ?

Comment: If you need to find the $x$ or $y$ value to determine the ordered pair $(x, y)$, then you use the original equation. To know if $dy/dx$ is undefined (vertical tangent), you only need to check $dy/dx$ and determine if/when there are values of x and/or y for which dy/dx is undefined.. Similarly, to know when $dy/dx = 0$ (horizontal tangent and/or looking for critical values), then you solve $dy/dx = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Tangent line is horizontal if $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$, note that the slope of the tangent line is equal to the derivative of the function. From above, since $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{\frac{-2x+5}{2y+13}}=0\implies -2x+5=0\implies x=\frac{5}{2}$. So, the answer in your question is zero. and it is undefined if the denominator is zero.